# Troubleshooting Docker-Redis Connection and Pub/Sub Error in Rust Code

Tags: docker, rust, redis, connection, rust-cargo

I am using Docker to connect to Redis. I have successfully established the connection to Redis. Everything is working fine until I create the pubsub instance. However, when I attempt to execute `pubsub.subscribe()`, it exits with the error `unexpected end of file`. Essentially, I am attempting to send data through it to verify if it is functioning correctly. Additionally, the Rust code is not inside the Docker container; is that the reason for the failure? How can I rectify this?

```
async fn main() -> Result<(), RedisError> {

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // reading the config file
    let config_file = std::fs::read_to_string("docker-compose.yml").expect("Unable to read file");
    println!("config_file: {:?}", config_file);
    let config: Config = serde_yaml::from_str(&config_file).unwrap();

    println!("config: {:?}", config);
    
    // creating the adress for the redis connection
    let address = format!("redis://{}:{}", config.services.redis.environment[1].split("=").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1], config.services.redis.ports[0].split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[0]);
    println!("address: {:?}", address);
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // let address = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379";

    // // connecting to redis   
    let client = redis::Client::open(address).expect("Unable to connect to redis");
    println!("Successfully connected to Redis!");

    // creating two connections
    let mut con1 = client.get_connection()?;
    let mut con2 = client.get_connection()?;
    println!("Successfully created two connections!");


    // creating a channel id
    
    let channel = "xasdsf".to_string();
    let message = "Hello, world!";

    let mut pubsub = con1.as_pubsub();
    println!("Successfully created a channel id!");

    // subscribing to the channel
    pubsub.subscribe(channel.clone())?;
    println!("subscribed to mychannel");

    
    // publishing to the channel
    con2.publish(channel.clone(), message)?;
    println!("published to mychannel");

    // receiving the message

    loop {
        println!("waiting for message");
        let msg = pubsub.get_message()?;
        let payload: String = msg.get_payload()?;
    
        println!("Received data on mychannel: {}", payload);
        println!("got message");

    }

    Ok(())

}
```

I am also adding docker-compose.yml for reference :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=""
      - REDIS_HOSTNAME=0.0.0.0
```